# MSDTC/DTCPing works in only one direction

Tags: msdtc

if i set up two windows server 2008 r2 machines, i can get distributed transactions to work in only one direction.  when i can get DTCPing to work successfully, the DTC is working.  DTCPing, though, only works when i initiate the test from one machine to the other, and not the other way around.

let's call my machines app and database.

if i start DTCPing on both and key app into the instance on database and press enter, DTCPing reflects success.

if i start DTCPing on both and key database into the instance on app, i do not get anything that says there was a failure, it just doesn't run to completion.  it looks like it completes the rpc test, but doesn't proceed to the bind test.  the logs do reflect an error, but my understanding is that it's related to a cluster check and these machines are not in clusters and that it doesn't matter.  if that's incorrect, please inform me, but i do see that same error in the log when i do the DTCPing in the direction that succeeds.

the output in the DTCPing window on app shows this:

```
DTCping log file: C:\DTCPing\APP1840.log
RPC server is ready
Please Start Partner DTCping before pinging
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
Please refer to following log file for details:
    C:\DTCPing\APP1840.log
Invoking RPC method on database
RPC test is successful
++++++++++++RPC test completed+++++++++++++++
Please start PING from database to complete the test
```

the output in the window on database shows this:

```
DTCping log file: C:\DTCPing\DATABASE1612.log
RPC server is ready
Please Start Partner DTCping before pinging
Please send following LOG to Microsoft for analysis:
    Partner LOG: APP1840.log
    My LOG: DATABASE1612.log
```

the log on app is this:

```
IP Configure Information
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . : app
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . : 10.40.100.2
                                         10.60.100.2
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
    NetBIOS Scope ID. . . . . . : 
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . : no
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . : no
    NetBIOS Resolution Uses DNS : no

Ethernet adapter {870B0C62-7C24-482A-ACCD-61B112ED77EB}:

    Description . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #5
    Physical Address. . . . . . : 00-50-56-01-01-9B
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . : no
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . : 10.45.20.50
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . : 10.45.20.1
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . : 
    Primary WINS Server . . . . : 
    Secondary WINS Server . . . : 
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970

++++++++++++lmhosts.sam++++++++++++

++++++++++++hosts      ++++++++++++

02-08, 12:49:53.496-->Error(0x424) at clutil.cpp @256
02-08, 12:49:53.496-->-->OpenCluster
02-08, 12:49:53.496-->-->1060(The specified service does not exist as an installed service.)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     DTCping 1.9 Report for APP  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
RPC server is ready
++++++++++++Validating Remote Computer Name++++++++++++
02-08, 12:50:03.589-->Start DTC connection test
Name Resolution:
    database-->10.45.20.48-->database
02-08, 12:50:03.667-->Start RPC test (APP-->database)
RPC test is successful
    Partner's CID:FF897F99-E4A4-47EE-9FD2-6B09BED00B86
++++++++++++RPC test completed+++++++++++++++
```

the log on database is this:

```
IP Configure Information
    Host Name . . . . . . . . . : database
    DNS Servers . . . . . . . . : 10.40.100.2
                                         10.60.100.2
    Node Type . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
    NetBIOS Scope ID. . . . . . : 
    IP Routing Enabled. . . . . : no
    WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . : no
    NetBIOS Resolution Uses DNS : no

Ethernet adapter {FCCFD12A-F8C1-4EB8-87D1-E2C2CFC07AB9}:

    Description . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter #6
    Physical Address. . . . . . : 00-50-56-01-01-99
    DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . : no
    IP Address. . . . . . . . . : 10.45.20.48
    Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
    Default Gateway . . . . . . : 10.45.20.1
    DHCP Server . . . . . . . . : 
    Primary WINS Server . . . . : 
    Secondary WINS Server . . . : 
    Lease Obtained. . . . . . . : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970
    Lease Expires . . . . . . . : Thu Jan 01 00:00:00 1970

++++++++++++lmhosts.sam++++++++++++

++++++++++++hosts      ++++++++++++

02-08, 12:49:47.953-->Error(0x424) at clutil.cpp @256
02-08, 12:49:47.953-->-->OpenCluster
02-08, 12:49:47.953-->-->1060(The specified service does not exist as an installed service.)
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
     DTCping 1.9 Report for DATABASE  
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
RPC server is ready
02-08, 12:50:02.822-->RPC server:DATABASE received following information:
    Network Name: database
    Source  Port: 49198
    Partner LOG: APP1840.log
    Partner CID: C94B257A-E177-4DFE-BC29-A33740ED59D9
```

should i expect that MSDTC would typically work in both directions?
is there a reason i would see this behavior?

Comment: also should note that by uninstalling msdtc, rebooting, and reinstalling, i can reverse which machine is able to initiate the test and have it successfully complete, but it still only works in one direction.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Comment: no, never did - thanks for reminding me - i should add an answer to that effect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

never did get this resolved.  ultimately wound up just getting the transactions to work in the correct direction and gave up on making it work both ways.

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced the same problem that you had.

I will recommend to you:

Follow this points in troubleshooting the MSDTC

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/distributedservices/2011/11/22/troubleshooting-msdtc-communication-checklist/

If all the steps are fine, The communication between the SQL server and the Webserver pass the WinRm Test. If, only the errors in the DTCPing persists follow the next steps.

Probably, the error is located in the CID of the machine. This tends to happened when using machines that are acreated based on existent images such the ones created by Softlayer or Aws.

You can recognized if that is the error because in the machine were the communication fails in the DTCPing you will get an Partner CID: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

Then follow the CID resolution steps in this page (Consider reinstalling). 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa561924.aspx

If you need more help, give me some feedback about it.